# Change the outline color of bootstrap caret

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to change the bootstrap caret color. Please see below the code:

```
<div class="share-popup dropup dropdown-toggle">
    Open Dropdown
    <ul class="share-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jason99/k43FT/. Following image will show you what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

I am playing with the following css class but can't figure out how to add outline in caret:

```
.dropup .caret {
    border-top: 6px solid #fff;
    bottom: -4px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Here's a codepen to see how a carret can be created/styled. http://codepen.io/dlim/pen/vxBur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create another triangle as a pseudo element on `.dropup .caret` like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k43FT/16/)

```
.dropup .caret:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid orange;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: -6px;
    right: -12px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to do it without to much hacking. You have to create a caret in a caret. Like this:

```
<div class="caret">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wftgC